# hardware acceleration in android unsharp paths

Tags: android, canvas, hardware-acceleration

I draw simple filled paths with canvas. I use

```
canvas.scale(scalex, scaley);
```

to larger and smaller the shapes.

When I switch to Hardware acceleration (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

and restart the app and zooming in ( canvas.scale ), the paths where ugly and unsharp?

Does anyone know why? Do I have to code something additianally to have the same draving, but accelerated?

Before Acceleration

[image: bfore HardwareAcceleration]

After Acceleration:

[image: After Acceleration]

Comment: This is a problem with some Android versions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996058/are-android-view-transformations-applied-after-rasterization/14045606#14045606 for some more details.